# How to access global $wp_meta_boxes variable on front-end?

Tags: metabox, wp-admin, front-end, globals

Is there a way to take the global `$wp_meta_boxes` variable to be used in the front-end? Currently the `$wp_meta_boxes` is accessible on specific admin pages only.

I've found a [similar question about this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/126128/27722). Its solution is to get the data via the `do_meta_boxes` hook, but I would like to access the variable without JS/AJAX, and in a front-end template.

Comment: Can I ask why do you need that?

Comment: TBH, I forgot why I need this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do what you are after - without AJAX, that is.

The problem lies with the fact that all/most of the meta boxes are added in an admin-specific context.

The [`add_meta_boxes`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_meta_boxes) action hook, for instance, is the most common (and appropriate) place to add custom meta boxes. And this very hook is fired in only three wp-admin files/pages.

And even if you think about firing the above action on the front-end by yourself, you can't get a hold of all those meta boxes that are **added** in an admin context only.

I, for myself, add custom meta boxes like so:

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpdev_154684_add_my_custom_meta_box' );
}

function wpdev_154684_add_my_custom_meta_box() {

    add_meta_box(
        /* ... */
    );
}
```

<sub>Of course, this is a strong simplification/abstraction of how the code actually looks like.</sub>

---

So, what then?

Since you linked to [my question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/126128/27722), I think you already found **one** way of getting admin-specific stuff - from somewhere other than the actual context.

I'm definitely not saying this is the only way. This is just what I came up with (with all the help from Shazzad and G.M.), for my very special context.

Comment: thanks for your respond, I'm actually still trying to find any hacky solution for this ( almost giving up :( ), for example using wp_remote_get, or include the hook on the template, still no luck so far.